# Why std::set::erase is not consistent with std::set::insert?

Tags: c++, algorithm, set

Why is the second set not subtracted from `myset`?  `myset.insert(second.begin(),second.end())` works as intended.

```
// erasing from set
int main ()
{
  std::set<int> myset;
  std::set<int> second;
  std::set<int>::iterator it;

  // insert some values:
  for (int i=1; i<10; i++) myset.insert(i*10);  // 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
  for (int i=3; i<5; i++) second.insert(i*10); 

  myset.erase(second.begin(), second.end()); // Why is the second set not subtracted from myset?  myset.insert(second.begin(),second.end()) works as intended.

  std::cout << "myset contains:";
  for (it=myset.begin(); it!=myset.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What output are you getting. What would you like to get differently?

Comment: [To quote from cppreference.com: "Removes the elements in the range `[first; last)`, which must be a valid range in `*this`."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase). That is to say, the iterators must belong to `myset`.

Comment: @Cornstalks my answer was independent of your comment ... great minds link alike.

Comment: @Cornstalks : Thanks for helping me understand the limitation.

Comment: Interesting - I've never thought about these methods from this point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::set::erase` expects iterators to the set you call it on.  Giving it iterators to another set will  not work.  What you want is [`std::set_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) which you pass to it both sets and it will output a new set that has all the elements in the first set that arent in the second set.  For you that would look like

```
std::set diff;
std::set_difference(myset.begin(), myset.end(), 
                    second.begin(), second.end(), 
                    std::inserter(diff, diff.begin()));
```

Comment: Is it more efficient than looping over the second set and calling myset.erase(it) for each element? myset is order of size 100 and second set is of order 10.

Comment: @AdityaBudaraju You'd have to profile it but I would think the performance is pretty comparable.  I like this method myself because it is a one liner.

Answer (score 1):

erase takes iterators inside the set it's working on

```
 Removes the elements in the range [first; last), which must be a valid range in *this.
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase